# strstr to find a word in a string using c returning true all the time

Tags: c, c-strings, turbo-c

Good Day,

So I decided to go trough my C again and started making a simple search the word in a string.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

main(){
char word[100];
char sentence[100];

clrscr();
printf("Enter a word: ");
fgets(word, 100, stdin);
getch();
printf("The word is : %s", &word);
getch();
printf("\nEnter a sentence: ");
fgets(sentence, 100, stdin);
getch();
printf("The sentence is: %s",&sentence);
getch();
if(strstr(sentence,word) == 0){
  printf("word found!");
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

The problem now is that whenever i try to search for the word in a string using `strstr`, it always returns **word found**. I also tried using `strcmp` but that will only compare the first instance of the string and stops when a match is not found so its not really advisable if you want to do a word searching in a string problem.

I haven't really made a program like this before, never needed one actually. So may I ask why is not working properly since according to its description `strstr` should be to search for a word in a sentence or did I just misunderstood it.

Also if you have any comments on my program feel free to say so, so that I may become aware of my mistake.

Thank you

**Example:
word: dog 

sentence: the dog is here 

should return true**

Comment: You are printing wrong `printf("The sentence is: %s",&sentence);`

Comment: @Armin I'm sorry but isn't that what I wrote?

Comment: Yes it is. I am pointing that out.

Comment: @magicianIam he means you don't need the `&`.

Comment: @Armin oh i see, sorry, would you mind telling me why i dont need to point to the address? thats what & is for right? thank you

Comment: "it always returns **word found**" -- No, you always print "word found" -- those are two totally different things and grasping that is necessary to being a programmer. "according to its description strstr should be to search for a word in a sentence or did I just misunderstood it" -- You didn't mention your understanding of its return value, so apparently you didn't read that or didn't pay attention to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
if(strstr(sentence,word) == 0)
```

should be

```
if(strstr(sentence,word) != NULL)
```

`strstr()` returns a pointer to the first occurence of `word` in `sentence` or `NULL` if the word was not found.

For details [please read here](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=strstr&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en).

---

Also using `fgets()` to read in the "strings" appends a `'\n'` to the end of the "strings". This prohibits successful comparsion.

To chop of the trailing `'\n'` you could do like this:

```
fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
{
  size_t size = strlen(word);

  if (size && ('\n' == word[size-1]))
  {
    word[size-1] = '\0';
  }
}
```

Comment: Good day @alk, I tried and it still was not working, it only worked when the word can be found at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: what would you suggest as an alternative to fgets?

Comment: @magicianIam: Nothing, using `fgets()` is a secure choice to do you are doing.

Comment: @magicianIam: A possible alternative would be `fscanf(stdin, "%99s", word);`. But be aware that using it without the `99` in this case, makes it dangerous, as it could lead to a buffer overflow.

Comment: `stdin` is the stream to read from: "Standard Input". The same as you use in your question to have `fgets()`to read from.

Answer (score 2):

> Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of str2 in str1, or a null pointer if str2 is not part of str1.

Returning NULL (0) essentially means that the string was NOT found.

Thus

```
if(strstr(sentence,word) == 0){
  printf("word found!");
}
```

Should be

```
if(strstr(sentence,word) != NULL){
  printf("word found!");
}
```

Source - http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr

Additionally as Armin points out, you shouldn't use the address operator, `&`, in your `printf`. `%s` expects to have a pointer passed to `printf` and using the name of the array as `sentence` is actually the same as a pointer to the start of the array, i.e `sentence == &sentence[0]`

Answer (score 1):

The `strstr()` function finds the first occurrence of the substring "needle" in the string "haystack" and it returns the pointer to the beginning of the substring or `NULL` if not found.

so your if statement should be

```
if(strstr(sentence,word) != NULL){
printf("word found");
}
```

Array name represents base address of its own, so writing

```
printf("%s",&word)
```

or

```
printf("%s",word)
```

both repesents base address of array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little correction in your code i.e.,

```
if(strstr(sentence,word) == 0){
 printf("word found!");
}
```

Change is: instead ==0 to !=0 which is equivalent to !=NULL,
in case of pointers 0 and NULL are same.
because NULL keyword is defined as:

```
#define NULL ((void *)0)
```

so change your code to

```
if(strstr(sentence,word) != 0){
 printf("word found!");
}
```